# Using T-SQL, how can I catch the OS error code?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

Microsoft SQL Server 2005+

When performing a database backup, I may get this error in SSMS:

Msg 3202, Level 16, State 2, Line 5

Write on "c:\dbbackup\dummy.bak" failed: 112(There is not enough space on the disk.)

Here, **112** is the OS error code, and the text in parenthesis is the OS error text.

My question is: **how can I get this info programmatically?**

If I put the BACKUP command in a TRY-CATCH block then I can use the ERROR_*() functions, but none of them contains this info.

The mentioned ERROR_*() functions are:

- ERROR_**NUMBER**(),
- ERROR_**MESSAGE**()
- ERROR_**SEVERITY**()
- ERROR_**STATE**()
- ERROR_**PROCEDURE**()
- ERROR_**LINE**()

I can only catch the info that is displayed in the first line of the error message (Msg 3202...etc) as well as the SQL error text: "BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally" (this is returned by the ERROR_MESSAGE() function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch block will return the last/terminating error only. There is a Connect item for that: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/277335/incorrect-error-number-passed-to-catch-block#

SSMS is a .net applicaton and uses SqlExeption to catch all exceptions in a batch. Errors property is a SqlErrorCollection which will contain all of the errors (depending on XACT_ABORT settings). Currently this is not possible with T-SQL by using TRY/CATCH

Comment: Thanks for the info, János.

Two things are left open:

1) Somehow, Management Studio is capturing the first (or the root cause of the) error. How does it do that?

2) The connect item was closed by Microsoft in 2007. Since then, 4 versions of SQL server have been released. It seems they did not fix this since 4 versions...

Answer (score 0):

Janos Berke was so kind and answered the question. Link: http://iamberke.com/post/2014/06/14/egymast-koveto-tobb-sql-hiba-kezelese.aspx#.U60vKr1V_cc
Text is in Hungarian but the thing is that basically this cannot be done in pure TSQL: you need an SQLException .NET object to catch multiple errors. Sample code can be found under the link.
Thanks Janos.